# c# - Make sure you have sufficient privileges to access this resource

Tags: c#

I get this error when I run

```
File.Create(Directory);
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Directory);
tw.WriteLine(value);
tw.Close();
```

It highlights

```
File.Create(Directory);
```

which should be obvious because it is trying to create a file there.
I want to know how to either bypass this which I highly doubt is possible, or request the user for sufficient permissions. Thanks!

Comment: You already seem to know *why* you're getting that exception. So I'm not totally clear on what you're asking... You'll want to wrap that in a try/catch and handling the situation accordingly (likely inform the user, as you mentioned, and gracefully stopping whatever you're doing in this code until they correct the permissions and try again or using a different directory altogether).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `File.Create` method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) could throw `UnauthorizedAccessException` in two cases

1. The caller does not have the required permission
   or
2. path specified a file that is read-only.

First, verify if path exists and it is not read-only (opened, maybe?). 
If previous does not hold the solution would be related to giving access to the file or the directory.

Comment: yes I understand this but I have no idea how to fix 1. and it is definately not 2.

Comment: Coming back to your question and comment on bypassing, I am not aware of such possibility. To grant access, first is to verify which user is running the code, then give the write permissions to the directory or the particular file to that user (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx).